# Why the sum of time-durations always returns zero, on a Google timesheet

Tags: google-sheets, time

How to add a **column containing duration times**, in format `[hh]":"mm`, and **sum** them?

- I've added the time durations as *hours:minutes* in the Column *A*. I've inserted them as specified in the formatting; *e.g.* I've typed `1:30`.
- I've formatted B2 and the whole Column A as `[hh]":"mm`, so that the hours are counted as amount and not as datetime reference.
- I've added the `SUM(A3:A5)` function in the *B2* cell.

Here a sample:

[image]
(from this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hvnivAmGX0ou-NudTK5o32UFSpxZTPLD265EcxC6MYs/edit?usp=sharing)

but, as you can see, the result of the `SUM()` function is always zero.

What's wrong? How to have a simple timesheet for total duration? (*without* having to generate them with a `startCell - endCell`)

Comment: This works in my sheet after following your steps. Can you provide public access to your Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(A3:A))), "[h]:mm"))
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't work; the formula was giving syntax error. I went to `"File->Document settings"` and choose to *"Always use English function names"*. Still didn't work, but I couldn't understand why you could do it easily and I am having problems. Then I went again to `"File->Document settings"` and **changed the language** to "United Kingdom". **Suddenly the time format inserted started to work as expected** and as shown in your screenshot.